# Grails 3.2.9 fails on grails prod run-app

Tags: grails

I'm getting these exceptions, from JSON not being found, to some tables on H2 that do not exist.

grails prod run-app throws these errors, it works OK on dev with grails run-app.

Cleaned the app but the errors persist.

Also build war seems to work OK.

Any clues about these issues with running prod from the console?

```
Configuring Spring Security Core ...
... finished configuring Spring Security Core

2017-08-13 12:09:01.072 ERROR --- [ost-startStop-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Table "REQUEST_MAP" not found; SQL statement:
select this_.id as id1_3_0_, this_.version as version2_3_0_, this_.config_attribute as config_a3_3_0_, this_.http_method as http_met4_3_0_, this_.url as url5_3_0_ from request_map this_ [42102-194]
server https://:cabolabs-ehrserver.rhcloud.com80/
File to commit 1374ffff-7458-4082-8ee3-6106722c10fa.xml
2017-08-13 12:09:04.915 ERROR --- [eduler_Worker-1] g.p.q.l.ExceptionPrinterJobListener      : Exception occurred in job: Grails Job

org.quartz.JobExecutionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sf/json/JSONObject
        at grails.plugins.quartz.GrailsJobFactory$GrailsJob.execute(GrailsJobFactory.java:111)
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
        at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sf/json/JSONObject
        at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder.<init>(HTTPBuilder.java:193)
        at groovyx.net.http.RESTClient.<init>(RESTClient.java:80)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:83)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:105)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:60)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:235)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:247)
        at com.cabolabs.ehrserver.EhrServerClient.<init>(EHRServerClient.groovy:44)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:83)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:105)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:60)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:235)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:271)
        at com.cabolabs.notes.CommitJob$_execute_closure1.doCall(CommitJob.groovy:36)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:294)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1027)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:414)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:430)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ResourceGroovyMethods.eachFile(ResourceGroovyMethods.java:1070)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ResourceGroovyMethods.eachFile(ResourceGroovyMethods.java:1088)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$936.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:274)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:56)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
        at com.cabolabs.notes.CommitJob.execute(CommitJob.groovy:29)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at grails.plugins.quartz.GrailsJobFactory$GrailsJob.execute(GrailsJobFactory.java:104)
        ... 2 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sf.json.JSONObject
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 48 common frames omitted

2017-08-13 12:09:04.942 ERROR --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Table "ROLE" not found; SQL statement:
select this_.id as id1_4_0_, this_.version as version2_4_0_, this_.authority as authorit3_4_0_ from role this_ where this_.authority=? limit ? [42102-194]
2017-08-13 12:09:04.998 ERROR --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:106)
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:182)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:148)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1934)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1903)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1881)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:925)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:342)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2622)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2605)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2434)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2429)
        at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:109)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1787)
        at org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:363)
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.query.AbstractHibernateQuery.singleResultViaListCall(AbstractHibernateQuery.java:785)
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.query.AbstractHibernateQuery.singleResult(AbstractHibernateQuery.java:775)
        at org.grails.datastore.gorm.finders.AbstractFindByFinder.invokeQuery(AbstractFindByFinder.java:35)
        at org.grails.datastore.gorm.finders.AbstractFindByFinder$1.doInSession(AbstractFindByFinder.java:29)
        at org.grails.datastore.mapping.core.DatastoreUtils.execute(DatastoreUtils.java:319)
        at org.grails.datastore.gorm.finders.AbstractFinder.execute(AbstractFinder.java:42)
        at org.grails.datastore.gorm.finders.AbstractFindByFinder.doInvokeInternal(AbstractFindByFinder.java:27)
        at org.grails.datastore.gorm.finders.FindOrCreateByFinder.doInvokeInternal(FindOrCreateByFinder.java:65)
        at org.grails.datastore.gorm.finders.FindOrSaveByFinder.doInvokeInternal(FindOrSaveByFinder.java:47)
        at org.grails.datastore.gorm.finders.DynamicFinder.invoke(DynamicFinder.java:174)
        at org.grails.datastore.gorm.finders.DynamicFinder.invoke(DynamicFinder.java:374)
        at org.grails.datastore.gorm.finders.FinderMethod$invoke$0.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
        at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi.methodMissing(GormStaticApi.groovy:173)
        at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEntity$Trait$Helper.staticMethodMissing(GormEntity.groovy:749)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeStaticMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1451)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokeMethod(InvokerHelper.java:899)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:168)
        at com.cabolabs.security.Role.staticMethodMissing(Role.groovy)
        at com.cabolabs.security.Role.$static_methodMissing(Role.groovy)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeStaticMissingMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1504)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeStaticMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1492)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaClassSite.call(StaticMetaClassSite.java:53)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
        at notes.BootStrap$_closure1.doCall(BootStrap.groovy:45)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:294)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1027)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1092)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1027)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:414)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:408)
        at grails.util.Environment.evaluateEnvironmentSpecificBlock(Environment.java:535)
        at grails.util.Environment.executeForEnvironment(Environment.java:528)
        at grails.util.Environment.executeForCurrentEnvironment(Environment.java:504)
        at org.grails.web.servlet.boostrap.DefaultGrailsBootstrapClass.callInit(DefaultGrailsBootstrapClass.java:62)
        at org.grails.web.servlet.context.GrailsConfigUtils.executeGrailsBootstraps(GrailsConfigUtils.java:65)
        at org.grails.plugins.web.servlet.context.BootStrapClassRunner.onStartup(BootStrapClassRunner.groovy:53)
        at grails.boot.config.GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.onApplicationEvent(GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.groovy:256)
        at grails.boot.config.GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.onApplicationEvent(GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.groovy)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:167)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:383)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:337)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:882)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:144)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:545)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:762)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:372)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:83)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:388)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:375)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp$run.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
        at notes.Application.main(Application.groovy:8)
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "ROLE" not found; SQL statement:
select this_.id as id1_4_0_, this_.version as version2_4_0_, this_.authority as authorit3_4_0_ from role this_ where this_.authority=? limit ? [42102-194]
        at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179)
        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableOrView(Parser.java:5465)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableFilter(Parser.java:1259)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSimpleFromPart(Parser.java:1934)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSimple(Parser.java:2083)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSub(Parser.java:1928)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectUnion(Parser.java:1746)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelect(Parser.java:1734)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:447)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:319)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:291)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:256)
        at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:564)
        at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:505)
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1204)
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.<init>(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:73)
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareStatement(JdbcConnection.java:288)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ProxyConnection.invoke(ProxyConnection.java:126)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:108)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ConnectionState.invoke(ConnectionState.java:152)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:108)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.TrapException.invoke(TrapException.java:40)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:108)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.AbstractCreateStatementInterceptor.invoke(AbstractCreateStatementInterceptor.java:66)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:108)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DisposableConnectionFacade.invoke(DisposableConnectionFacade.java:81)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy86.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy$LazyConnectionInvocationHandler.invoke(LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy.java:376)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy88.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy$TransactionAwareInvocationHandler.invoke(TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy.java:240)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy88.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:146)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:172)
        ... 92 common frames omitted


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':bootRun'.
> Process 'command '/Users/Lucia/.sdkman/candidates/java/8u131-zulu/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
compile "net.sf.json-lib:json-lib:2.4"
```

To your `build.gradle` dependencies section

As far as the tables not found, looks completely unrelated.

Comment: I'm curious about why JSON works on dev but not in prod.